# how to convert dates in MySQL while using LOAD LOCAL INFILE?

Tags: mysql, xml, date

I am trying to get a xml file into MySQL using LOAD LOCAL INFILE and while doing that convert date formats. The xml file, `notacts.xml`, looks like this (only one element-set `<ROW/>` is shown):

```
<?xml version='1.0' ?>
    <ROW>
        <field name="ID">12779293</field>
        <field name="AA_NUMBER">162</field>
        <field name="CONTENT">some text</field>
        <field name="DATE">30-12-1643</field>
        <field name="FA_NUMBER">5115.1</field>
        <field name="LAST_CHANGE_DATE">10-07-15</field>
    </ROW>
```

My MySQL database table "acts" contains fields using the names of the attributes of the field-elements of the xml file. When I use this SQL:

```
LOAD XML LOCAL INFILE 'notacts.xml' INTO TABLE acts
ROWS IDENTIFIED BY '<ROW>'
SET recordID=NULL
```

Everything is ingested fine, except for the two dates: the database field "DATE" gets as value for all entries: "0000-00-00" (the date in the example is: 30th of December 1643) and the database field "LAST_CHANGE_DATE" gets as value: 2010-07-15 (the date in the example is: 10th of July 2015).

When I try to solve this by adding these two lines to the SQL:

```
SET DATE = STR_TO_DATE(@DATE, '%d-%m-%Y'),
LAST_CHANGE_DATE = STR_TO_DATE(@LAST_CHANGE_DATE, '%d-%m-%y')
```

I get an error:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SET DATE = STR_TO_DATE(@DATE,'%d-%m-%Y')' at line 4
```

My MySQL version is 5.6.16.

I think the problem lies in the fact that in the two additional lines I 'call' `@DATE` and `@LAST_CHANGE_DATE` instead of something like: `@field name="DATE"` and `@field name="LAST_CHANGE_DATE"`, but I don't know how to solve this, so any suggestion to deal with this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do something like this:

```
LOAD XML LOCAL INFILE 'notacts.xml'
INTO TABLE acts
ROWS IDENTIFIED BY '<ROW>'
(column1, @DATE, column3, @LAST_CHANGE_DATE, ...)
SET DATE = STR_TO_DATE(@DATE, '%d/%m/%Y'),
LAST_CHANGE_DATE = STR_TO_DATE(@LAST_CHANGE_DATE, '%d/%m/%Y')
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I tried that , but I still got the same error message ...

Comment: Thanks for the hint, although I didn't understood it correctly at first :-)

Answer (score 0):

Taking into account that my table 'acts' also has a field 'recordID' which is set to INT(10) and AUTO_INCREMENT, I used:

```
LOAD XML LOCAL INFILE 'notacts.xml' INTO TABLE acts
ROWS IDENTIFIED BY '<ROW>'
(column1, column2, column3, column4, @DATE, column6, @LAST_CHANGE_DATE)
SET recordID=NULL
SET DATE = STR_TO_DATE(@DATE, '%d-%m-%Y'),
LAST_CHANGE_DATE = STR_TO_DATE(@LAST_CHANGE_DATE, '%d-%m-%y')
```

I also used this, so discarding the recordID field:

```
LOAD XML LOCAL INFILE 'notacts.xml' INTO TABLE acts
ROWS IDENTIFIED BY '<ROW>'
(column1, column2, column3, @DATE, column5, @LAST_CHANGE_DATE)
SET recordID=NULL
SET DATE = STR_TO_DATE(@DATE, '%d-%m-%Y'),
LAST_CHANGE_DATE = STR_TO_DATE(@LAST_CHANGE_DATE, '%d-%m-%y')
```

Both commands resulted in the same above mentioned error message

Answer (score 0):

Ah, sorry, stupid of me, I finally got it to work, but like this ofc:

```
LOAD XML LOCAL INFILE 'notacts.xml' INTO TABLE acts
ROWS IDENTIFIED BY '<ROW>'
(recordID, ID, AA_NUMBER, CONTENT, @DATE, FA_NUMBER, @LAST_CHANGE_DATE)
SET recordID=NULL
SET DATE = STR_TO_DATE(@DATE, '%d-%m-%Y'),
LAST_CHANGE_DATE = STR_TO_DATE(@LAST_CHANGE_DATE, '%d-%m-%y')
```